# InfoPath Drop Down Validation

Tags: infopath

I have a set of drop down lists about 12 in an InfoPath form. I need to set validation where users can only select from at most 5 drop down lists. How do I do this in InfoPath 2010?

Answer (score 0):

You can make an invisible textbox with default value 0.

If user select something from drop-down list, make textbox value ++1.
And make a rule to disable each dropdown list if textbox value == 5.